# How can I make my code simpler?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to find similar letters

```
charList = CharacterRange["a", "l"];
ls = ImageData@Binarize@Rasterize@# & /@ charList;
Table[{i}~Join~Nearest[Complement[ls, {i}], i, 1], {i, ls}];
% /. Rule @@@ Table[{ImageData@Binarize@Rasterize@ii, ii}, {ii, charList}]
GraphPlot[Rule @@@ %, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
Clear["`*"]
```

I think my code could be better. How can I refactor it?

Comment: Better in what way? Shorter? Easier for Mathematica novices to understand?

Comment: I would like more Shorter.

Comment: Why? Trust me -- The main thing is that the code is readable (assuming performance is not a problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a lot wrong with your code, which I find quite sophisticated. The one thing I'd suggest is that the piece `Table[{ImageData@Binarize@Rasterize@ii, ii}, {ii, charList}]` isn't needed, since `charList` and `ls` already give you want you need with the simple use of `Thread` to put the `Rule` elements in.

The following gives the same result as your version:

```
charList = CharacterRange["a", "l"];
ls = ImageData@Binarize@Rasterize@# & /@ charList;
Table[{i}~Join~Nearest[Complement[ls, {i}], i, 1], {i, ls}] /. 
 Thread[ls -> charList]
GraphPlot[Rule @@@ %, DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

The one other thing I'd suggest, which is purely stylistic, is to avoid the use of `%` in code that you regularly use. It's ok if you are just experimenting, but there is always the risk that people will accidentally evaluate cells out of order, so that `%` isn't the thing you expect it to be. I would suggest naming the expression on the third line, like so:

```
charList = CharacterRange["a", "l"];
ls = ImageData@Binarize@Rasterize@# & /@ charList;
pairs = Table[{i}~Join~Nearest[Complement[ls, {i}], i, 1], {i, 
    ls}] /. Thread[ls -> charList]
GraphPlot[Rule @@@ pairs, DirectedEdges -> True,  VertexLabeling -> True]
```

Of course, this assumes that the expression now defined as `pairs` is giving the result you want. You could have different results depending on the font size and font family that *Mathematica* assumes when rasterizing text.

Comment: A further tweak is to note that `{i}~Join~Nearest[Complement[ls, {i}], i, 1]` is the same as `Nearest[ls, i, 2]`. So you could define `nf = Nearest[ls -> charList]` and `pairs = nf[#, 2] & /@ ls`

Comment: Thanks. `Dimensions /@ (ImageData@Binarize@Rasterize@# & /@ {l, m, n})` gives {{15, 7}, {15, 8}, {15, 7}}, it's not my expect.